# Have border wrap around text

Tags: html, css, layout

Suppose I have a div with some text in it

```
<div id='page' style='width: 600px'>
  <h1 style='border:2px black solid; font-size:42px;'>Title</h1>
</div>
```

The border for the heading will extend all 600 pixels across the page, but I want the word "Title" to fit tightly inside. However, I don't know ahead of time how many pixels wide the word is so I can't for example put the "Title" inside a div and set its width explicitly.

Is there an easy way to make a border fit around text that does not fully extend horizontally across an area?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is because `h1` is a block element, so it will extend across the line (or the width you give).

You can make the border go only around the text by setting `display:inline` on the h1

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/XGRwy/1/

Answer (score 16):

Try putting it in a span element:

```html
<div id='page' style='width: 600px'>
  <h1><span style='border:2px black solid; font-size:42px;'>Title</span></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this and see if you get what you are aiming for:

```html
<div id='page' style='width: 600px'>
  <h1 style='border:2px black solid; font-size:42px; width:fit-content; width:-webkit-fit-content; width:-moz-fit-content;'>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do it is to make the display an inline block

```
<div id='page' style='width: 600px'>
  <h1 style='border:2px black solid; font-size:42px; display: inline-block;'>Title</h1>
</div>
```

if you do this it should work

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, if that's what you want, but you could make the inner div an inline-element. This way the border should be wrapped only around the text. Even better than that is to use an inline-element for your title.

Solution 1

```
<div id="page" style="width: 600px;">
    <div id="title" style="display: inline; border...">Title</div>
</div>
```

Solution 2

```
<div id="page" style="width: 600px;">
    <span id="title" style="border...">Title</span>
</div>
```

Edit:
Strange, SO doesn't interpret my code-examples correctly as block, so I had to use inline-code-method.

Comment: For some reason Markdown refuses to format code blocks nested within lists (either `ul` or `ol`).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Didn't know that the parser made a list out of this. I fixed it now :)